# How do I set decimal values in 1D blend tree?

Tags: animator, animation-controller

I have created a 1D blend tree.
It is being used for a 3rd Person Controller.

The blend tree consists of 3 animations:

1. aim pistol down to the floor
2. aim pistol at middle of the screen (straight forward)
3. aim pistol up in the sky

[image]

To determine the blend value (which animation should be played), I inspect the current mouse position and convert it a value between 0 (aim low) and 1 (aim high). The middle position would be 0.5.
Here is my code:

```
float f = Input.mousePosition.y / Screen.height;

Debug.Log("Blendval " + f.ToString());//
_animator.SetFloat("BlendVal", f);
```

[image]

I tried to insert these decimal values in the blend tree like this:

[image]

However, this doesn't work.
Unity converts my "0.5" to 0.
I don't see why.

I can instead use integers like this:

[image]

Why doesn't Unity allow me to use 0, 0.5 and 1?
Why do I have to use "other" values like -1, 0 and 1?

Thank you!

Edit:

I don't understand what is going on.
I have just typed 0.5 here instead of 0:

[image]

And then suddenly I could enter the values as desired, and even "Automate Threshold" would do what I expected:

[image]

But now it won't accept negative values anymore.

Strange.

Comment: Looks like Unity thinks the parameter is of type "Trigger". Is your BlendVal parameter type set to "Float" (Animator Window, Parameters tab)?

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Thank you but I think it's Float. I have added a screenshot showing this. I have manually entered the value "0.5", and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in Unity:

If you type the decimal separator as ".", it works.

But not if you use ",".

You can use "," anywhere else in Unity, and it will automatically be converted to ".", but not in the Blend Tree.

I have filed a bug report.

I will remove this question once Unity fixed it.

Comment: Ahh, [they might be using the wrong culture parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo?view=net-5.0#parsing-user-strings) in their string-parsing function.